# Horizontal line after inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I need the last red line to be equal width as all the previous ones.
The width of UL container could be different (that makes nth selectors useless here).
And the height of each LI's line could be different too.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZX9W/34/

```
<ul>
    <li>Medium medium medium medium medium contnent.</li><!--
    --><li>Short contnent.</li><!--
    --><li>Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long contnent.</li><!--
    --><li>Short contnent.</li><!--
    --><li>Even more long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long contnent.</li><!--
    --><li>Short contnent.</li><!--
    --><li>Medium medium medium medium medium contnent.</li>
</ul>

li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 222px;
    border-top: solid 10px rgba(255,0,0,.3);
}
```

Hope to find solution without JavaScript help.

**upd.** The border color should be transparent. So be careful with overlapping.

**upd2.** The red line shouldn't be too long (it should ends right after last column + addition margin (margin-right:20px)).

Comment: The number of columns you want are fixed? Or depends on user's screen size?

Comment: The number of columns are not fixed. It depends on user's screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: block` instead of `display: inline-block` for your list:

```
li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZX9W/3/)

or you can set different css for the last li:

```
li:last-child:before {
    width: 450px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZX9W/1/)**

Comment: 1 Demo: It's just not what I'm looking for (I need float-like elements...). 2 Demo: I don't know the width I'd need there because it depends on container's width (or user's screen size).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so how about something like this?
Using 9999px as a value for width *seems* and probably *is* kind of hacky, but whatever works, right?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZX9W/26/

And here is the CSS used:

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px #aaa dashed;  
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 9999px;
    border-top: solid 1px #f00;
}
```

Of course it all depends on the fact, that the **UL** *has to have* `overflow: hidden` + I added some additional styling: removing the right padding and `padding-top: 10px` is there because we want to show the first row's `:before` red lines, for which you defined `top: -10px`

Comment: Sorry I forget that border color I need is transparent. Your hack won't work as it should http://jsfiddle.net/6ZX9W/32/ And the other thing the red line is too long (it should ends right after last column + margin-right:20px).

Comment: The border color is something I put in there to see the layout better and it is a thing you can totally change/remove.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using li:before 
try using:-

```
    li:nth-child(2n+1):before {
        border-top: 1px solid #FF0000;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        width: 214%; /*(or 444px)*/
   }
```

Comment: I don't know how many elements will fit in the UL container. So I don't know the required width and nth-child expression.

Comment: doesnt matter ...

either the no of elements would be odd or even... and in either case you want the red line to cover the entire UL. so, if you just put the red line 'before' the odd elements,(for width = 200%) it will cover the entire width regardless of wheather the even child exists or not. 

so you can use li:nth-child(odd)

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got the point ;) Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3GF8R/2/)

I removed the position on your `<li>` tags and remove `top` values from `:before` selector, and so change the border to a 1px height with background.

Comment: Works good for solid colors. But if you'll try to change size of container and see how opacity will be changing (in fact :before elements are just overlaying each other) http://jsfiddle.net/3GF8R/3/ And the red line is too long at the right (it should ends right after last column + margin-right:20px).

Comment: Visually it looks correct (until you try to change UL's width).